# Comparar cada palavra do texto dado e guardar as linhas em que o texto aparece

Tags: java

Tenho os Seguintes métodos em java, o método split separa cada palavra de um texto e guarda em um TreeSet<> para manter a ordem alfabética e retorna o TreeSet<> em questão. O metodo compare deve pegar esse TreeSet<> e comparar com o texto passado por parâmetro, pegando cada palavra, usando o método .getLineNumber da classe LineNumberReader e guardar cada linha aonde aquela palavra aparece colocar em um Map<> cada palavra e a lista aonde a mesma aparece.

```
public Collection<String> split(String book){
    try{
        FileReader path = new FileReader(book);
        LineNumberReader read = new LineNumberReader(path);
        String line;

        while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
            line = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase();
            split = line.split(" ");

            for(String s : split){
                if(s.length() >= 1 && !palavras.contains(s)){
                    palavras.add(s);
                }
            }           
        }

        path.close();
        read.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Caminho para o arquivo invalido!");

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }

    return palavras;  
}   

public Map<String, List<Integer>> compare(Collection<String> list, String book){
    FileReader path;
    try {
        path = new FileReader(book);
        LineNumberReader read = new LineNumberReader(path);
        String line;         

        for(String s : list){
            ArrayList<Integer> lineNro = new ArrayList<>();
            while((line = read.readLine()) != null){                    
                line = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase();
                split = line.split(" ");                    
                for(String a : split){                        
                    if(s.equals(a)){
                        lineNro.add(read.getLineNumber());
                    }
                    words.put(a, lineNro);                        
                }
            }
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> e : words.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        path.close();
        read.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Spliter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Spliter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return words;      
}
```

O resultado obtido é uma lista de palavras mas todas as palavras recebem a mesma lista de Integer. O resultado esperado Seria uma lista de palavras e para cada palavra uma lista composta pelas linhas aonde aquela palavra aparece.

Comment: Qual o problema do seu codigo? Qual o resultado obtido e qual o esperado? Se possivel crie um [EMCV](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Editado, obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Como não postou um exemplo compilável, vou passar mais ou menos o que deve ser feito para conseguir ter a lista da forma que deseja:

```
public Collection<String> split(String book){
    try{
        FileReader path = new FileReader(book);
        LineNumberReader read = new LineNumberReader(path);
        String line;

        while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
            line = line.replaceAll("[â-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase();
            //Faz mais sentido ter split como uma variavel local aqui
            String[] split = line.split(" ");

            for(String s : split){
                if(s.length() >= 1 && !palavras.contains(s)){
                    palavras.add(s);
                }
            }           
        }

        path.close();
        read.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Caminho para o arquivo é inválido!");

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }

    return palavras;  
}   
//O map PRECISA de ser do tipo <String, List<String>> em vez de inteiros
public Map<String, List<String>> compare(Collection<String> list, String book){
    FileReader path;

    try {
        path = new FileReader(book);
        LineNumberReader read = new LineNumberReader(path);
        String line;         

        for(String s : list){
            //Não se recomenda usar ArrayList<> foo = new ArrayList<>()
            List<String> lineNro = new ArrayList<>();
            while((line = read.readLine()) != null){                    
                line = line.replaceAll("[â-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase();
                String[] split = line.split(" ");                    
                for(String a : split){                        
                    if(s.equals(a)){
                        //Adicione a linha que contém a palavra
                        lineNro.add(line);
                    }
                    // cria o mapa da forma esperada
                    words.put(a, lineNro);                        
                }
            }
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : words.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        path.close();
        read.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return words;      
}
```

não garanto que esteja completamente correto, mas acredito que te dará uma boa direção de como prosseguir.

**Observação:** acredito que agora a variável `lineNro` deva ser substitiuida por algo mais significativo.